# EXCEL: Formula to get length of number as displayed in cell (incl. displayed leading zeros)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a user-supplied field which stores a numeric GTIN as text. I validate that the field is 7 or 11 characters in the next cell.

It's easy enough to add a formula such as `=OR(LEN(A1)=7,LEN(A1)=11)`, but there are cases where the user pastes from another excel document, for instance, a number with a custom format of 11 0's. The cell appears to contain 11 characters with a few leading zeros, but the LEN formula sees fewer characters (ex. the cell may display `00123456789`, but `LEN(A1)` = 9). I'm at a loss as to how I can control for this.

Without macros, how can I find the length of this *displayed value*?

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Then your cell has a custom format on it to show the extra `00` and Excel only sees the `123456789`.  And since formulas cannot "see" the formatting of the cells you will need vba.

Comment: That's a shame. Yes, that is the situation. Basically, I calculate the final check digit based on the length of the GTIN, and the leading zeros in the custom format disallow me from determining this.

Comment: Is there an issue with converting everything to 11 characters or the lesser of 7 or 11 characters?  You could do something along the lines of `=RIGHT("00000000000"&A1,11)` and copy down.  The 11 can be adjusted to 7 if length of a1 is <= 7.

Comment: How about check if the cell is `TEXT` or `NUMBER` first before getting the length?  Something like this: `=IF(ISTEXT(A10),LEN(A10),IF(ISNUMBER(A10),IF(LEN(A10)<=7,7,11),"Check Format"))`.  I am not sure why the fields can be 7 or 11 since I am not familiar with GTIN, so I assume if the number is less than or equal to 7, the length should be 7, otherwise is 11.  Or you can use `=TEXT(A2,"00000000000")` to convert number to text.  Each 0 represent a character.

Answer (score 1):

A quick user defined function (aka UDF) can replace the standard LEN worksheet function.

```
function displayLEN(rng as range)
    displayLEN = len(rng(1).text)
end function
```

Put this into a standard module code sheet. Use just like the worksheet's LEN function; e.g. `=displayLEN(A1)`